# Fancy Box jquery - opening behind php overlay

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

www.yorkshirephotographer.net/new

you can view all code

The gallery/portfolio page is working in standard mode - when you click a photo it opens correctly

When the website optimises for mobiles/tablets the gallery photo is shown behind the page block/php block - needs to be infront?

Thanks
Ben

ps - click 'portfolio' to see gallery pictures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't to do with the Javascript, really: it's a CSS problem. Your `#content` area has a z-index of 10000 in your `style-600.css`; that's higher than the fancybox (`z-index: 8010`). Change that, and you should be OK.